# How to make working TFTP server on CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, networking, centos, centos6, tftp

I'm trying to setup TFTP server on CentOS 6.2.
The `/etc/xinet.d/tftp` configuration file is the following:

```
service tftp
{
    disable = no
    socket_type     = dgram
    protocol        = udp
    wait            = yes
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args     = -s /tftpboot -vvv
    per_source      = 11
    cps         = 100 2
    flags           = IPv4
}
```

The selinux and firewall are disabled.
The `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` files are empty.
When I'm trying to get a file from the TFTP server, the file transfer always failed and I see the following errors into `/var/log/messages`

```
Jul 11 03:16:53 localhost xinetd[4155]: xinetd Version 2.3.14 started with libwrap loadavg labeled-networking options compiled in.
Jul 11 03:16:53 localhost xinetd[4155]: Started working: 1 available service
Jul 11 03:17:00 localhost xinetd[4155]: START: tftp pid=4157 from=192.168.10.3
Jul 11 03:17:00 localhost in.tftpd[4158]: RRQ from 192.168.10.3 filename 1
Jul 11 03:17:00 localhost in.tftpd[4158]: sending NAK (0, Permission denied) to 192.168.10.3
Jul 11 03:17:01 localhost in.tftpd[4159]: RRQ from 192.168.10.3 filename 1
Jul 11 03:17:01 localhost in.tftpd[4159]: sending NAK (0, Permission denied) to 192.168.10.3
Jul 11 03:17:03 localhost in.tftpd[4160]: RRQ from 192.168.10.3 filename 1
```

The `tftpboot` directory permissions are (output of the `ls -l` command):

```
drw-rw-rw-.   3 root root  4096 Jul 11 03:32 tftpboot
```

I also see that the `tftpboot` directory is shown (by `ls -l`) with green background (unlike other files/directories) (Why? As I know the green background is for sticky bit only).

What I did wrong? How can I make TFTP server working?

Comment: The green background in `ls -l --color` means that the file or directory is world writable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `/etc/xinet.d/tftp` configuration file is correct.

The permissions of `/tftpboot` should be 755 or `drwxr-xr-x`.

Make sure chkconfig --list shows tftp enabled under xinetd.

```
xinetd based services:
        chargen-dgram:  off
        chargen-stream: off
        daytime-dgram:  off
        .
        .
        rsync:          on
        tcpmux-server:  off
        tftp:           on
```

Comment: Definitely need +rx for directories.

Comment: old thread i know - but suspect OP eventually had to mess with selinux settings. if 'setenforce 0' alleviates the issues, there are selinux issues with /tftpboot

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a couple of times.

Verify `/etc/xinetd.conf` to see if your server is named to allow access to the `xinetd` daemon and check `/etc/host.allow` to see if `tftp` and `in.tftpd` is allowed on your network.

Answer (score 0):

We went through and did all of the above (have run tftp many times) and could not get it to work on CentOS7.  Write Permisson problem no matter what we did.  Finally took @justjeff suggestion and "setenforce 0" and it worked.

kernel has all the latest patches.

Issue with selinux again.